# CloudFront For Wordpress Site On EC2

Tags: cache, amazon-ec2, dynamic-dns, amazon

I have an EC2 instance, with LAMP Stack. I'm following this guide for CloudFront setup for a wordpress site.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/how-to-accelerate-your-wordpress-site-with-amazon-cloudfront/

Here's settings I've done so far in cloudfront for this distribution.

**General Settings**

[image]

**Origin Settings**

[image]

**Behaviour Settings**

[image]

[image]

[image]

but both `/wp-includes/* & /wp-content/*` behaviours pointing to EC2 origin.

All's setup well, and site contains product information with their images stored in WP database. Whn I visit site, most of these images showing properly except 4 5 images, which show blank grey thumbnails only.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It feels like we're about 3 steps removed from the problem, here. The images without thumbnails -- is there any consistency to them? Have they just not generated yet? Is there a way to force their generation? Is there a broken link or permission issue somewhere? Perhaps if you walked us through the actual steps you took, someone could see something missing.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller... yes Jeff if I point the domain directly to A record of the server, it is showing thumnails fine, but when point that domain to CloudFront Distribution's CNAME, it shows blank thumnails, but not all, half of the thumbnails are showing fine. I'll update Q section for details.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I've updated the question, if you can please review it again.

Comment: yes it seems to me too, cause when I access the domain directly on server, it's showing all content. but CF doesn't load all images. Oh and I'll try Webmasters forum, btw is there a way to migrate Q from one forum to other? probabaly Admins with Advance privileges can do.

Comment: I do see a "amazon-cloudfront" tag at Webmasters. I can migrate your question there if you'd like; or you can simply delete this one here and re-ask it there. Let me know your preference!

Comment: @JeffSchaller Please migrate it, cause by removing questions, it affects my reputatuon, I don't have much reputation, and It wouldn't be suitable for me to lose it, since I seldom seek guidance from Stack when I face any issues.

Comment: Be happy to. Just want to point out that your post currently has no votes on it here on U&L, so I wouldn't expect any change to your reputation. Migrating it will also delete it from here.